# Minimising a matrix equation to find 'best fit' affine matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, affine-geometry

Here is my problem:

I have an image divided into segments.  Each segment consists of pixels with coordinates (x,y) called vector $v$, each pixel has a length 3 vector RGB called $I(v)$.  I want to find an affine matrix (3x3) $A$ which minimises $I(v) - A[v^T 1]^T$, however not just for the pixel, but for the whole segment.  This means that the minimisation equation becomes $\sum\limits_{v \in segment}||I(v) - A[v^T 1]^T ||^2$.

How would I go about minimising this?  Preferably with functions in numpy/scipy or similar (e.g. MATLAB/Octave).

Comment: What is an affine matrix? What is a segment? What does the notation $[v^T 1]^T$ mean (I would interpret $1$ as a vector of ones, which would mean that $v^T1$ is a scalar, which would mean the transpose is superfluous)?

Comment: a segment is a portion of the image.  the notation $[v^T 1]^T$ is the homogeneous version of $[x y]$ i.e. $[x y 1]^T$.  An affine matrix is a matrix which represents an affine transformation.  in this case a 3x3 with a 1 in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Assuming that a segment is a finite set, then this is just least squares in $\mathbb{R}^8$.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: The bottom-right corner of $A$ is the value of the blue channel of pixel $(0,0)$; I'm pretty sure you don't need a $1$ there. Also, you should perform minimization on each colour channel independently, as you'll get the same answer.

Comment: After the action of the matrix $A$, are you looking at mapping back to $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $[x,y,z]\mapsto[x/z,y/z]$?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that a segment can be written as $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $x = (x_1^T,x_2^T,x_3^T)^T \in \mathbb{R}^8$ represent the 'free' elements of $A$. Here $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $x_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$. That is, we have:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} x_1^T \\ x_2^T \\ x_3^T & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

For each $i \in \{1,...,n\}$, define $B_i \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 8}$, and $b_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$ by:
$$B_i = \begin{bmatrix} (v_i^T 1) & & \\ & (v_i^T 1) & \\ & & v_i^T\end{bmatrix}, \; \; b_i = I(v_i) -\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Then
$$ || B_ix-b_i||^2 = ||I(v_i) - A[v_i^T 1]^T ||^2.$$

Form $B \in \mathbb{R}^{3n \times 8}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{3n}$ by 'stacking' the $B_i, b_i$ on top of each other.

Then you can write the problem as $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^8} || Bx-b||^2$.